# Pthread is not present

Tags: php, pthreads, php-pthread

i want to install the pthreads extension in wampserver php 7.4.4 but i don't know why is not work.

I followed this steps :

1) Download this file "php_pthreads-3.2.0-7.2-ts-vc15-x64"

2) Extract "pthreadVC2.dll" to my php root and add this to PATH

3) Extract "php_pthreads.dll" to my /ext file

4) Add to the good php.ini this line "extension=pthreads"

5) Restart wamp

My PHP info :

```
System  Windows NT DESKTOP-AIE5C8O 10.0 build 18363 (Windows 10) AMD64
Build Date  Mar 17 2020 13:42:17
Compiler    Visual C++ 2017
Architecture    x64
Configure Command   cscript /nologo /e:jscript configure.js "--enable-snapshot-build" "--enable-debug-pack" "--with-pdo-oci=c:\php-snap-build\deps_aux\oracle\x64\instantclient_12_1\sdk,shared" "--with-oci8-12c=c:\php-snap-build\deps_aux\oracle\x64\instantclient_12_1\sdk,shared" "--enable-object-out-dir=../obj/" "--enable-com-dotnet=shared" "--without-analyzer" "--with-pgo"
Server API  Apache 2.0 Handler
Virtual Directory Support   enabled
Configuration File (php.ini) Path   C:\Windows
Loaded Configuration File   C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.41\bin\php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files     (none)
Additional .ini files parsed    (none)
PHP API     20190902
PHP Extension   20190902
Zend Extension  320190902
Zend Extension Build    API320190902,TS,VC15
PHP Extension Build     API20190902,TS,VC15
Debug Build     no
Thread Safety   enabled
Thread API  Windows Threads
Zend Signal Handling    disabled
Zend Memory Manager     enabled
Zend Multibyte Support  disabled
IPv6 Support    enabled
DTrace Support  disabled
Registered PHP Streams  php, file, glob, data, http, ftp, zip, compress.zlib, phar
Registered Stream Socket Transports tcp, udp
Registered Stream Filters   convert.iconv.*, string.rot13, string.toupper, string.tolower, string.strip_tags, convert.*, consumed, dechunk, zlib.*
```

thanks

Comment: Which error do you get?

Comment: Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pthreads' (tried: c:/wamp64/bin/php/php7.4.4/ext/pthreads (Le module spécifié est introuvable.), c:/wamp64/bin/php/php7.4.4/ext/php_pthreads.dll (La procédure spécifiée est introuvable.)) in Unknown on line 0

Comment: You're on windows, eg. `extension=php_pthreads.dll`... did you also copy the `.pdb` files accordingly?

Comment: No, it didn't say in the documentation to use it. I think that the problem come to here : https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads/issues/929#issue-410636734

Comment: yeah, seems so. I got it running on PHP 7.1 a while back and wasn't aware that the whole extension was canceled.

Comment: thanks, i used parallel and is a good extension ! Is very simple to use.